# Mock function call in controller with silex and phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, silex

I'm building a PHP application with Silex and PHPUnit for unit tests.

In my controller I've this following code :

```
 public  function indexAction(Application $app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('admin/pages/index.html.twig', array(
        'pages' => $this->pageDao->getAllPage()
    ));
}
```

In my unit test I want to check **getAllPage** was called.

I've wrote following unit test :

```
 public function testIndexAction()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();
    $stub   = $this->getMockBuilder('Lsi\Dao\PageDao')
        ->setMethods(array('getAllPage'))
        ->setConstructorArgs(array(DatabaseFactory::getDatabaseForTesting()))
        ->getMock();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/private.pages/');

    $this->assertEquals($client->getResponse()->isOk(), true);

    $stub->expects($this->once())->method('getAllPage');

}
```

Controller route retuns content but I've an error on method expectation :

**Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to be trying to mix up unit and integration / functional tests into one thing, which is a bit odd.

Comment: What's the best way to test controller routes ?

Comment: You make the request as you have done, and test that the output is what you expect. You don't test that method x on object y gets called and so on, that's for unit tests generally. This is just imo.

Comment: Thank you for your help.